# converting from Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab

```
c = imread('focus.jpg');
```

I have a 3D array *( image )* in  m.file ,I want to use this
    array in C++,how can i pass this array  to C++ file

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can call MATLAB Engine directly in `C++`.

Check out [Call MATLAB Functions from C and C++ Applications](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html) for more info and examples.

---

**Edit:** On the other hand, it seems you don't need to do this, you can simply load this image directly in `C++`, e.g. using `OpenCV`.

Comment: @user3411910 You don't need to. In C++ with OpenCV, you can directly use `Mat img = imread('focus.jpg');`.